# Gae + Struts2 + Spring3 + Hibernate4 + MySQL in localhost doesn't create http session and datastore is always empty

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, google-app-engine, esapi

I have a problem with datastore and hibernate, I have been able to integrate Gae + Struts2 + Spring3 + Hibernate4 + MySQL in localhost and everything seems to work, but when I try to create a session in HTTP, the session is not created or session.getLastAccessedTime() is always 1970-01-01(default value). When I go to datastore link in http:localhost:8080/_ah/admin there is no session created.

I use ESAPI for the security and this method:

```
public boolean isSessionTimeout() {
    HttpSession session = ESAPI.httpUtilities().getCurrentRequest().getSession(false);
    if (session == null)
        return true;
    Date deadline = new Date(session.getLastAccessedTime() + IDLE_TIMEOUT_LENGTH);
    Date now = new Date();
    return now.after(deadline);
}
```

returns always true.

I have enabled sessions in appengine-web.xml and I dont understand the problem as long as this kind of configuration works in tomcat but in appengine version 1.9.2 there is some kind of problem.

I build the project in maven like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                <webResources>
                    <!-- in order to interpolate version from pom into appengine-web.xml -->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${appengine.app.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <jvmFlags>
                    <jvmFlag>-Dappengine.generated.dir=${project.basedir}/appengine</jvmFlag>
                    <jvmFlag>-Ddatastore.backing_store=${project.basedir}/local_db.bin</jvmFlag>
                </jvmFlags>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I have as first filter in my web.xml, ESAPIFilter which contains:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    try {
        ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Logger.SECURITY_FAILURE, "Error in ESAPI security filter: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    try {
        // figure out who the current user is
        try {
            ESAPI.authenticator().login();
        } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "Unauthorized");
        }
        // log this request, obfuscating any parameter named password
        ESAPI.httpUtilities().logHTTPRequest(request, logger, Arrays.asList(obfuscate));
        // check access to this URL
        if (!ESAPI.accessController().isAuthorizedForURL(request.getRequestURI())) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "Unauthorized");
        }

        // check for CSRF attacks
        //ESAPI.httpUtilities().verifyCSRFToken(request);
        // forward this request on to the web application
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        // set up response with content type
        ESAPI.httpUtilities().setContentType(response);
        // set no-cache headers on every response
        // only do this if the entire site should not be cached
        // otherwise you should do this strategically in your controller or actions
        ESAPI.httpUtilities().setNoCacheHeaders(response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(Logger.SECURITY_FAILURE, "Error in ESAPI security filter: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        request.setAttribute("message", e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        // VERY IMPORTANT
        // clear out the ThreadLocal variables in the authenticator
        // some containers could possibly reuse this thread without clearing the User
        try {
            ESAPI.clearCurrent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(Logger.SECURITY_FAILURE, "Error in ESAPI security filter: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to implement a custom login, but I can't use http sessions for some unknwon reason, ah_SESSION is not created in my local datastore. Is there any example on how to use sessions for java in Appengine? I have been searching but with no results...

Comment: The fact that its always returning `null` tells me that you haven't configured app-engine to integrate with ESAPI.  For example, in a legacy application that I integrated ESAPI into, I had to set a factory setting in log4j.properties that pointed to ESAPI's logging implementation.

Comment: You've left out some very important context... did you fully implement ESAPI's Authenticator setup, or are you just adding ESAPI into a legacy application?

Comment: The Javadoc on the DefaultHttpUtilities class says this:

` * Typically, this is done by calling the Authenticator.login() method, which
 * calls setCurrentHTTP() automatically. However if you want to use these methods
 * in another application, you should explicitly call setCurrentHTTP() in your
 * own code. In either case, you *must* call ESAPI.clearCurrent() to clear threadlocal
 * variables before the thread is reused. The advantages of having identity everywhere
 * outweigh the disadvantages of this approach.`

Comment: Judging by that documentation, you either have a configuration with your Authenticator config, OR you're not explicitly setting the request, hence why its always returning `null`

Comment: In my update I'm showing for each request(I have ESAPIFilter as first filter in my web.xml) I set the request/response for my authenticator with: ESAPI.httpUtilities().setCurrentHTTP(request, response); and in the end clear the threadlocal as per ESAPI reccomandation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem somehow the session was created with default session.getLastAccessedTime()=0 and I set this value with the current time like this:

```
    public boolean isSessionTimeout() {
    HttpSession session = ESAPI.httpUtilities().getCurrentRequest().getSession(false);
    if (session == null)
        return true;
    long lastAccessedTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
    if(session.getLastAccessedTime()!=0){
        lastAccessedTime=session.getLastAccessedTime();
    } 
    Date deadline = new Date(lastAccessedTime + IDLE_TIMEOUT_LENGTH);
    Date now = new Date();      
    return now.after(deadline);
}
```

finally everything works now and I can locally create a session, I have not tried it in production.

Comment: If you have fully solved the problem, please mark your answer as "accepted" so we can drop the "unanswered questions" queue.